When considering the air friction, does the missile trajectory reversable?
When seeing a video of a missile hitting a target, someone would argue that it is fake, since the video is played backwards. I know that Newtonian mechanics is time reversal if we do not considering the air friction, therefore we cannot tell if the video is played forward or backward.
My question is when air friction is considered, can we tell whether the video is played backwards?
For simplicity, let's assume the missile has acquired its full speed at the launch point (that is, no chemical reaction push during the path), and executing the free motion afterwards.

wouldn't you notice that the video is being played backwards because the actual impact and detonation of the missile are certainly not time-symmetric?

If the missile appears to be launched nose-down from a pile of rubble by a large explosion, it's probably backwards.

You need a video clip that is clear enough to be able to accurately estimate the missile's speed and height at different times. From the missile's speed you can calculate its kinetic energy; from its height you can calculate its potential energy. If the sum of the missile's kinetic energy and potential energy appears to be increasing with time then there is definitely something strange going on - the video is being played backwards, or is being played at a variable speed, or the missile is on a non-ballistic trajectory.


when air friction is considered, can we tell whether the video is played backwards?

Consider a situation as simple as a movie of a ball leaving one person's hand and landing in another person's hand. Interaction with air molecules changes the trajectory of the ball. Is it possible that all of the air molecules that hit the ball just happen to hit it in a way that causes it to speed up during its entire flight instead of slowing it down. Absolutely. Yes.
Is it probable? If you had a million pairs of people doing the experiment all day, every day, on every planet in the universe from now until the end of the universe, it would be very safe to bet that none of those people would ever see it actually happen.
